# how do I display a googlechart in ruby?

Tags: ruby, url, uri, fxruby, gchart

I was wondering how to display a chart made with gchartrb in ruby. I tried to do it by simply requiring the picture from the URL given but that gives the error "Bad URI". how do I do it? thanks

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'google_chart'





# Pie Chart
GoogleChart::PieChart.new('320x200', "Pie Chart",false) do |pc|
  pc.data "Apples", 40
  pc.data "Banana", 20
  pc.data "Peach", 30
  pc.data "darn", 600

  $chart = pc.to_url

end

require 'fox16'

include Fox

class Image_Viewer <FXMainWindow
  def initialize(app)
    super(app, "Image Viewer", :opts => DECOR_ALL, :width => 500, :height => 450)
    require 'open-uri'
    @pic = Kernel.open($chart, "rb")
    @pic2 = FXPNGImage.new(app, @pic.read)
    FXImageFrame.new(self, @pic2)

end
  def create
    super
    self.show(PLACEMENT_SCREEN)
end

end


app = FXApp.new
mainwin = Image_Viewer.new(app)

app.create
app.run
```

Comment: no need for global variable $chart, pc = GoogleChart::PieChart { .. }; pc.to_url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that `URI::parse` does not like the URL google generate (probably because of the use of `|`). So encode it before using:

```
@pic = Kernel.open(URI::encode($chart))
```